# Where is the button click event in Devexpress repositoryItemButtonEdit control?

Tags: events, button, grid, click, devexpress

I have a devexpress grid, one of the columns is a repositoryItemButtonEdit control. I want the following functionality: if user click the button, another form will pop up. But I cannot find the button click event for this repositoryitemButtonEdit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The RepositoryItemButtonEdit provides the ButtonClick event.  Please take a look at the screenshot attached.[image]

Comment: How did you go to the above screen?

Comment: This is the PropertyGrid (View-->Properties Window)

Comment: Instead of using ButtonClick, I would recommend to use ButtonPressed.

Answer (score 0):

create your own Button click event
Write following line.

```
repositoryItemButtonEdit1.ButtonClick =+ repositoryItemButtonEdit1_ButtonClick;
```

and then Create following event function.

```
private void repositoryItemButtonEdit1_ButtonClick(object sender,DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.ButtonClickEventArgs e)
 {
         //Your Code;   

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put griView.**OptionsBehavior.Editable**= false;

if this is true Click event doesn't fire